# How to properly import structs in Rust?

Tags: rust

I wanted to create a struct named "Filme" and include it in the main.rs, but I've been struggling with that. Here is the Filme.rs file:

```
pub struct Filme{
    pub nome: String,
     pub duracao: u8,
     pub categorias : String,
 
 }
 
 impl Filme{
     pub fn new(nome:String, duracao:u8, categorias: String) -> Filme{
         Filme {
             nome: nome,
             duracao: duracao,
             categorias: categorias,
         }
     }
}
```

main.rs file:

```
pub mod Filme;

fn main() {
    let mut filme = Filme::new("Vingadores".to_string(),90,"Ação e Aventura".to_string());
    println!("{}",filme.print_categorias());
}
```

By the way, both of them are in the same directory.

I keep getting the error "error[E0425]: cannot find function `new` in module `Filme`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't name the mod the same as your struct. You'd have to do `Filme::Filme` each time you reference the struct, or import it as as different alias. Just rename the module to something like `filme`.

But if you must,

```rust
mod Filme;

fn main() {
    let mut filme = Filme::Filme::new("Vingadores".to_string(), 90, "Ação e Aventura".to_string());
}
```

Or

```rust
use Filme::Filme as Film;

fn main() {
    let mut filme = Film::new("Vingadores".to_string(), 90, "Ação e Aventura".to_string());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Filme` is the name of the file, where new ins't exported from.
You wanna use `Filme::Filme::new()`